# Best approach for saving highlighted areas on geographical map

Tags: design, database, database-design, map

I am designing an application that allow users to highlight areas of a geographical map using a tool that is like brush or a pen. The tool basically draw a circle with a single click and continue drawing those circles with mouse move.

Here is an example of drawing made by moving the tool. It is pretty much same as Microsoft Paint.

[image]

Regardless of programming language what is best approach (most inexpensive approach) for saving this kind of data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an implementation of MVC objects in Google Maps JavaScript API V3. It allows map objects to store state and update their presentation automatically.
There is a [DEMO](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/articles/mvcfun/step5) of moving and resizing a circle which may provide what you require. The full tutorial can be seen [HERE](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/articles/mvcfun)

Comment: +1. This is better than my answer because it provides a complete solution with minimal coding. Internally the library seems to be doing the same thing as what I had outlined though.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: Thank you for references. I find out [this](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolygonOptions) a better match for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any mapping libraries that support highlights outright but if you want to do this with Google Maps or Yahoo GeoService then you can simply record the latitude and longitude of the bounds of the highlight area in a database.

On loading the map again, you can restore the highlight area from those bounds by rendering points using the lat/long. The approach will also work with resizable and transformable maps.

Obviously, the more complicated shapes you support the messier the implementation would get. Simplest would be to support shapes that follow a simple 2 variable equation (e.g., circles or rectangles).